# Output a Java window as a webcam stream

Tags: java, ffmpeg, streaming, transparency, webcam

I would like to write a program perferably in Java that can display animated overlays on a screen.

The screen will then be broadcast streamed over the internet using a separate program called x-split.

A good way to do this would be to create a transparent window in java which will display animated files (with transparancy) and the output of this window (Its display) should ideally appear in the webcam device list so it can be easily picked up by x-split which will allow it to be arranged ontop of the game screen I'm currently broadcasting.

An example program of this type would be one where a webcam image is displayed and "virtual glasses" overlayed over the image of a persons face which could then be transmitted as an output cam.

I have found the java 6u10-translucent-shapes library to create the transparent window but I don't know how to stream it.

I've read a few things to suggest that JMF and FFMpeg might be the way to go, but I'm not sure what to install and how.

Any help or pointers to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May `Java Web Start` be a solution?

Comment: I think Java Web Start is for starting applications using java. I need to write an application that outputs the java window as a webcam stream so I don't think it is a solution, thx. anyway.

Comment: You really need to clarify what you are trying to do here if you want anyone to help you... For one, why does a webcam have anything to do with your the rest of your question?

Comment: Just updated the question to clarify it a bit, you're right, it wasn't very clear.

Comment: starcraft? anyways, is what you want to do the typical setup casters use where you have the game and certain ui elements are covered by this fake frame? if this is the case: doesn't x-split stream everything that's visible on your screen anyways?

Comment: Not necessarily starcraft, but thats the kind of idea. I want to create a program that I can give to people that will create user created animated scenes that pop up when you click hot keys... such as a 3D animated creature running on screen with a banner saying "comming next... this." etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but what about an external program which streams your screen? Something like http://screen-stream.en.softonic.com ?

Comment: I am trying to create a program that adds overlays to a broadcast stream. I thus want to stream animated .gif images as a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Use java.awt's Robot class. It has a getScreenCapture(Rectangle) method which can be used to get BufferedImages of a portion of the screen. These BufferedImages can be edited with code, then can made to be flashed by having a full screen application display itself (and disappear to recapture the new Image.). Alternatively, you could filter it by using a  transparent java full screen application using the above method, and displaying it on your applet to be "x-treamed".

However, my biggest question is how do you expect to control your game anyway? Also, why are you expected to something this big for something that can be easily solved.

It would be simpler and way more synchronized if you just used a screen recording software to turn it into a movie, then use Windows Movie Maker to modify it to your needs. **You do not need to waste your time on code**. =)

I hope this helped.

Comment: He needs a live stream, so your last paragraph is kind of not an option at all... The idea with `java.awt.Robot` might work although you would have to to all the stream creation yourself.

Comment: I will be streaming games simultaneously usings xsplit's dx10 screen capture. So the game I am playing will be broadcast to a twitch.tv account. The purpose of this program is to add overlays to this broadcast (animations) over the top of the game output in real time by pressing hotkeys. This functionality isn't achievable with current software limiations.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an undecorated `JFrame` and the `AWTUtilities` class (I think that was what you found in Java6u10 for `Window` transparency) and do all your animation there. Use `java.awt.Robot.getScreenCapture(Rectangle)` to capture an image every *x* milliseconds. Use `javax.swing.Timer` to do the timing:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(x, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        arrayOfImages[imageCount] = java.awt.Robot.getScreenCapture(r);
        count++;
    }
});
```

I found a Java wrapper - Jffmpeg - to use (http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/download.html). You'll need JMF - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html - and some other stuff written in the Jffmpeg Documentation page. FMJ (http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php) is another option.

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) needs to be downloaded with [Git](http://git-scm.com/)

Finally, this thread from another forum (http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/youtube/330165-command-line-program-convert-image-video.html) somewhat shows you how to convert saved images to video. **You may want to skip the Jffmeg step altogther. Instead you could save all the images to file, and the convert it to video using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String) to execute the command line. But if you do this you won't be able to make your program platform-independent**

Videos in Java are a bit tedious and annoying, so you may want to switch to another language, with easier libraries and API's, altogether.